# errors with webdriver.Firefox() with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using python 3.5, firefox 45 (also tried 49) and selenium 3.0.1

I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Then I got the error message:

```
C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
C:/Users/A/Desktop/car/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/A/Desktop/car/test.py", line 4, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x0000000000EB8278>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
self.stop()
File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

What can I do? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using firefox ver >47.0.1 you need to have the `[geckodriver][1]` executable in your system path. For earlier versions you want to turn marionette off. You can to so like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['marionette'] = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Thanks Dean Fenster!

Comment: and I got:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'